# spring-hateoas 0.8.0.RELEASE compatibility with Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I'm using 0.8.0.RELEASE version of spring-hateos, which has spring libraries (spring-core and spring-webmvc) in version 3.2.3.RELEASE as a compile time dependencies.

However, in runtime I would like to use spring-core and spring-webmvc in version 4.2.2.RELEASE.

Does anyone know if this version of spring-hateos is compatible with latest version of spring libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/resources/changelog.txt), support for Spring 4.0.x is started on version `0.17.0.RELEASE`

> Changes in version 0.17.0.RELEASE (2015-03-05)
>   - #311 - Upgrade to latest Spring 4.0.x.
>   - #304 - Add build profiles for Spring 4.x.

Comment: Yep, I know that. It still does not answer my question. I asked if Spring 4 can be used with version 0.8.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Then the answer is no. It is because Spring 4 support is started on version 0.17.0.RELEASE. Which is the point of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's compatible

> org.springframework:spring-core   3.2.3.RELEASE
>   (Required )   4.2.3.RELEASE (Newest)
>   org.springframework:spring-webmvc 3.2.3.RELEASE
>   (Required )   4.2.3.RELEASE (Newest)

You can see here

https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas/0.8.0.RELEASE

Comment: Are you sure that the 'newest' column indicates the latest version being compatible? Isn't it displaying all the latest version for all the libraries?